# Working out prime factors

Tags: prime-factorization

I am having issues working out questions similiar to the below. I understand the general concept, but is there something I am missing to be easily about to see that the prime factors of 899 are 23 and 31?

5. Express the following as a product of prime factors:
   (a) 26; (b) 100; (c) 27; (d) 71;
   (e) 64; (f) 87; (g) 437; (h) 899.

ANSWERS:
5. (a) 2 × 13; (b) 2 × 2 × 5 × 5; (c) 3 × 3 × 3; (d) 71 × 1; (e) 2 × 2 × 2 × 2 × 2 × 2; (f) 3 × 29; (g) 19 × 23; (h) 29 × 31.

Comment: I'm not sure I like how they give that the prime factors of $71$ are $71$ and $1$, because $1$ is not a prime number. If that's what's in your textbook, it's suboptimal.

Comment: It sounds like you're not missing anything - when in doubt, just use the slow method of trial division. With experience you'll learn more tricks like the one for 899 in the posted answer.

Comment: There are also lots of [shortcuts](https://www.mathsisfun.com/divisibility-rules.html) for testing for small divisors.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to $899$ is to realize it's "close" to $900$, a perfect square.

More specifically,

$$900 = 30^2 \text{ so } 899 = 30^2 - 1$$

but then, using the difference of squares formula $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$, and that $1^2 = 1$, we have

$$899 = (30-1)(30+1) = 29 \cdot 31$$

Comment: Okay, that definately makes sense. Thanks for the assistance all :)